# How to check if a system app can be uninstalled like a normal app?

Tags: android, root, uninstallation

### Background

I am trying to learn about querying for apps info, how the installation works and how system apps behave. I'm trying to make an app that clarifies which apps can be uninstalled even if they are system apps.

### The question

Actually I want to ask 2 questions that are related to the title:

1. given a package name of an system app, how can I know that it's possible to uninstall it using the normal way (and not by using root) ?
2. Since I don't want to mess with apps and I want to do some experiments, suppose my app has root permissions and i want it to install another app as a system app, but also choose if it should or shouldn't be allowed to be uninstalled, how do I do that?

Comment: You can add System App only at android os source build time. Which are not removable.

Answer (score 0):

System apps are added into `/system/app` folder during the build of Android OS. `/system` partition in Android is mounted as read-only. Thus, you cannot delete any system application if you don't have root.

If you want to install a new application having a root permission I advice you to experiment in the following way:

1. Remount your `/system` partition as read-write.
2. Copy the apk file of your application into `/system/app` folder.
3. Remount your partition as read-only.

Coping application apk file into `/system/app` folder has a side effect of installation of this application.

Comment: are you sure that no system apps can be uninstalled (using the normal way) ? not even apps that can be downloaded on the play store (like flipboard) ? about the way to convert an app to a system app,can you please post a sample code (suppose the apk file is in the assets folder) ? can a system app uninstall itself? if not , can it do it using root permissions? how?

Comment: If you install application from Google Play, then the application is installed into /data folder that is mounted as read-write and thus, this application is not system (we can call it as user application). As for code I do not have examples, but I think you can find them in the Internet, I gave you the instructions what to look for.

Comment: actually, apps are usually installed to "/data/app" or "/mnt/asec" , but that doesn't matter. can you please post a link to how to achieve the conversion? also, please answer the other questions . i've asked them because i wish to achieve both things- if the user will uninstall the normal app, the system app that was installed with it will "self destruct" too, so no traces will be remained (that's the points of uninstallation).